# running console application from batch file with command line arguments, How to pass arguments value at run time?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net, batch-file

I have a VB.net console application with command line arguments.
Like ("-Arg1=Value1 -Arg2=Value2 -Arg3="Value 3")
this i'm passing arguments from project properties -> Debug ->Command line arguments.

My plan is to run this console application from batch(.bat) file. I can able to run like this.

```
@echo off

D:\Project\Bin\Debug\abc.exe %* -Arg1=Value1 -Arg2=Value2 -Arg3="Value 3"
```

But my expectation is while running console application it need to ask values for

```
-Arg1, -Arg2 & -Arg3
```

I need to pass values at run time.

Comment: Have you looked at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/command-line-compiler/how-to-invoke-the-command-line-compiler

Comment: Unable to reproduce the problem.  These command-line arguments are being passed to my sample application from a batch file as expected.  Can you elaborate on how you're able to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
Set /P "Value1=Enter Arg1 :"
Set /P "Value2=Enter Arg2 :"
Set /P "Value3=Enter Arg3 :"
D:\Project\Bin\Debug\abc.exe %* -Arg1=%Value1% -Arg2=%Value2% -Arg3="%Value3%"
```